# Record and Recognize music from URL

Tags: python, json, numpy, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I am using an open source audio fingerprinting platform in python [DeJavu](https://github.com/lenlight/dejavu) that can recognize music from disk and from microphone.
I have tested the recognition from disk and it is amazing. 100% accuracy.

I seek assistance on how to add a class "BroadcastRecognizer"
This will recognize music from a URL online stream example online radio  [http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p]
Because the music in the radio stream is constantly changing, would like to set it to recognize after every 10 seconds.

## Here is the recognize.py

```
import dejavu.fingerprint as fingerprint
import dejavu.decoder as decoder
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import time


class BaseRecognizer(object):

def __init__(self, dejavu):
    self.dejavu = dejavu
    self.Fs = fingerprint.DEFAULT_FS

def _recognize(self, *data):
    matches = []
    for d in data:
        matches.extend(self.dejavu.find_matches(d, Fs=self.Fs))
    return self.dejavu.align_matches(matches)

def recognize(self):
    pass  # base class does nothing


class FileRecognizer(BaseRecognizer):
def __init__(self, dejavu):
    super(FileRecognizer, self).__init__(dejavu)

def recognize_file(self, filename):
    frames, self.Fs, file_hash = decoder.read(filename, self.dejavu.limit)

    t = time.time()
    match = self._recognize(*frames)
    t = time.time() - t

    if match:
        match['match_time'] = t

    return match

def recognize(self, filename):
    return self.recognize_file(filename)


class MicrophoneRecognizer(BaseRecognizer):
default_chunksize   = 8192
default_format      = pyaudio.paInt16
default_channels    = 2
default_samplerate  = 44100

def __init__(self, dejavu):
    super(MicrophoneRecognizer, self).__init__(dejavu)
    self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    self.stream = None
    self.data = []
    self.channels = MicrophoneRecognizer.default_channels
    self.chunksize = MicrophoneRecognizer.default_chunksize
    self.samplerate = MicrophoneRecognizer.default_samplerate
    self.recorded = False

def start_recording(self, channels=default_channels,
                    samplerate=default_samplerate,
                    chunksize=default_chunksize):
    self.chunksize = chunksize
    self.channels = channels
    self.recorded = False
    self.samplerate = samplerate

    if self.stream:
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()

    self.stream = self.audio.open(
        format=self.default_format,
        channels=channels,
        rate=samplerate,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=chunksize,
    )

    self.data = [[] for i in range(channels)]

def process_recording(self):
    data = self.stream.read(self.chunksize)
    nums = np.fromstring(data, np.int16)
    for c in range(self.channels):
        self.data[c].extend(nums[c::self.channels])

def stop_recording(self):
    self.stream.stop_stream()
    self.stream.close()
    self.stream = None
    self.recorded = True

def recognize_recording(self):
    if not self.recorded:
        raise NoRecordingError("Recording was not complete/begun")
    return self._recognize(*self.data)

def get_recorded_time(self):
    return len(self.data[0]) / self.rate

def recognize(self, seconds=10):
    self.start_recording()
    for i in range(0, int(self.samplerate / self.chunksize
                          * seconds)):
        self.process_recording()
    self.stop_recording()
    return self.recognize_recording()


class NoRecordingError(Exception):
pass
```

## Here is the dejavu.py

```
import os``
import sys
import json
import warnings
import argparse

from dejavu import Dejavu
from dejavu.recognize import FileRecognizer
from dejavu.recognize import MicrophoneRecognizer
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE = "dejavu.cnf.SAMPLE"


def init(configpath):
""" 
Load config from a JSON file
"""
try:
    with open(configpath) as f:
        config = json.load(f)
except IOError as err:
    print("Cannot open configuration: %s. Exiting" % (str(err)))
    sys.exit(1)

# create a Dejavu instance
return Dejavu(config)


if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Dejavu: Audio Fingerprinting library",
    formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', nargs='?',
                    help='Path to configuration file\n'
                         'Usages: \n'
                         '--config /path/to/config-file\n')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--fingerprint', nargs='*',
                    help='Fingerprint files in a directory\n'
                         'Usages: \n'
                         '--fingerprint /path/to/directory extension\n'
                         '--fingerprint /path/to/directory')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--recognize', nargs=2,
                    help='Recognize what is '
                         'playing through the microphone\n'
                         'Usage: \n'
                         '--recognize mic number_of_seconds \n'
                         '--recognize file path/to/file \n')
args = parser.parse_args()

if not args.fingerprint and not args.recognize:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(0)

config_file = args.config
if config_file is None:
    config_file = DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
    # print "Using default config file: %s" % (config_file)

djv = init(config_file)
if args.fingerprint:
    # Fingerprint all files in a directory
    if len(args.fingerprint) == 2:
        directory = args.fingerprint[0]
        extension = args.fingerprint[1]
        print("Fingerprinting all .%s files in the %s directory"
              % (extension, directory))
        djv.fingerprint_directory(directory, ["." + extension], 4)

    elif len(args.fingerprint) == 1:
        filepath = args.fingerprint[0]
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            print("Please specify an extension if you'd like to fingerprint a directory!")
            sys.exit(1)
        djv.fingerprint_file(filepath)

elif args.recognize:
    # Recognize audio source
    song = None
    source = args.recognize[0]
    opt_arg = args.recognize[1]

    if source in ('mic', 'microphone'):
        song = djv.recognize(MicrophoneRecognizer, seconds=opt_arg)
    elif source == 'file':
        song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, opt_arg)
    print(song)

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Here is the stream http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p

Comment: Sadly, that isn't going to work, as dejavu finger prints a discrete piece of music, you are attempting to link to a continuous stream of chat, jingles, music etc.

Comment: Thanks @RolfofSaxony . Was thinking of linking it to a continuous stream of music. Will not have chats, jingles. Using a free online radio broadcast, I will broadcast music only. All the songs I will be broadcasting I will have fingerprinted them.

Comment: Dejavu currently records audio from microphone and recognizes. How can we enable Dejavu to record audio from and online stream, then we can recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think that you need a discrete "piece" of audio, so you need a beginning and an end.
For what it is worth, start with something like this, which records a 10 second burst of audio, which you can then test against your finger-printed records.
Note: that this is bashed out for python 2, so you would have to edit it for it to run on python 3

```
import time, sys
import urllib2
url = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p"
print ("Connecting to "+url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10.0)
fname = "Sample"+str(time.clock())[2:]+".wav"
f = open(fname, 'wb')
block_size = 1024
print ("Recording roughly 10 seconds of audio Now - Please wait")
limit = 10
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < limit:
    try:
        audio = response.read(block_size)
        if not audio:
            break
        f.write(audio)
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Error "+str(e))
f.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
print("")
print ("10 seconds from "+url+" have been recorded in "+fname)

#
# here run the finger print test to identify the audio recorded
# using the sample you have downloaded in the file "fname"
#
```

Comment: Thanx a million @Rolf of Saxomy. Testing now :)

Comment: Have tested. It records 10sec of audio successfully :).

Comment: Thanks @Rolf of Saxony. Tested multiple times and it's working flawlessly. 
Much appreciation. One last query. How can we enable the script to record continuously when we run it, then it can save the recordings after every 10 seconds.

Comment: Insert a 'while True:' loop before the response line. That will endlessly repeat everything after it.

Comment: Thanks again @Rolf of Saxomy.

Comment: Everything is working perfectly @Rolf of Saxomy. Much appreciation.
The code I am using to identify the recorded wav files, is set to identify one file, therefore it keeps recognizing the same song.

'# Recognize audio from a file
 song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "radio/sample.wav")'

How can we make it to recognize the recorded wav files, as soon as they are saved. This means each time it will recognize the newly saved wav file.

Comment: song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "radio/sample.wav")

Comment: I have replaced the file name with fname. Seems to work well.

Comment: Glad to hear that you sorted it out. A tick on the useful answer "Up" button would be appreciated, as I don't think that the answer I provided was technically "Correct".

Comment: Done. The answer you provided by @Rolf was the best for far. And am very content.
I have noted that I will end up having alot of saved recordings. How can we delete the recordings as soon as they are recognized for fingerprinting?

Comment: The sequence can be: Recording the wav, recognizing the saved wav,then deleting the recognized wav. and it can loop like that.
This means we shall not have alot of saved wav files eating up space. Thanks again

Comment: Don't bother, make the file name a fixed name (Sample.wav), open it with write, as is already being done, record to it, recognise it and then loop back to open it with write again.

Comment: Changed it to a fixed name. Works perfectly. Thanks a million @Rolf.